# Horário saindo com resultado inesperado

Tags: python, python-3.x, time

Estou executando um código que printa as horas no terminal porém quando eu uso o código abaixo ele me trás um valor totalmente errado na hora:

Código:

```
from time import gmtime, strftime
print(strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S +0000", gmtime()))
```

Segue o valor que ele retorna:

[image: Resultado com 3 horas de diferença]

Comment: E como podemos saber o que está errado? Pra mim está certo. Por acaso isto dá o resultado que espera? `print(strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S +0000", localtime()))`

Comment: Sim, assim foi sem nenhuma anomalia, por acaso saberia me dizer onde poderia estar o erro em meu código? Pois segui exatamente o código de sua documentação

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 1):

Você quer imprimir a hora local e a função correta para isto é a [`localtime()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.localtime), e não a `gmtime()` que te dá a hora chamada universal (sem fuso horário).

```
from time import localtime, strftime
print(strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S +0000", localtime()))
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/56pwE1). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/xdxguaiw-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Typing/Localtime.py).

Só tome cuidado porque em muitos casos o correto é trabalhar com hora universal e não local. Inclusive vemos várias perguntas aqui de pessoas com dificuldade por começarem usando errado em sistemas e depois não consegue arrumar mais.

Conceitualmente já há um erro nesse `+0000` fixo que dá uma informação enganosa, e mesmo um `+0300` só estará certo por coincidência em certas épocas do ano. Mas o assunto é absurdamente extenso para colocar aqui.